# Error: Port 1033 in use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I has last executed my ASP.NET program yesterday. But when today I again opened to run it, it showed me a Microsoft Visual Studio error that port 1033 is in use.

How can I solve this error? Where should I change to make the port available?

My web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial catalog=sshopping"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Close every program that connects to internet (like open browsers) then check again or use a program like TCPView that shows you which program is using the required port

Comment: In project settings you can have asp.net development environment use a free port every time instead of a specific port.

Comment: Where is the option of project setting. I have tried it by closing all the browsers

Answer (score 1):

Might be some other service using port `1033`. try setting some other random portno. and follow these steps.

- In the Properties pane, click the down-arrow beside Use dynamic ports
  and select False from the dropdown list. This will enable editing of
  the Port number property.
- In the Properties pane, click the text box
  beside Port number and type in a port number. Click outside of the
  Properties pane.This saves the property settings.
- Each time you run a
  file-system Web site within Visual Web Developer, the ASP.NET
  Development Server will listen on the specified port.

For more Clarity check these links

- [How to set a fixed port for the Developer Web Server?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2008/11/07/tip-21-did-you-know-how-to-set-a-fixed-port-for-the-developer-web-server.aspx)
- [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Visual Studio Web Development Sever. Go to the properties inside of the project, go to the web tab. There is an option "Auto Assign Port" make sure it is selected. If that doesn't work change it manually by selecting "Specific Port" and setting a port that is not used.